# Error in node-opencv

Tags: javascript, node.js, opencv

I installed node-opencv for win10 x64. But when I run my app included opencv get an error.

```
>node app.js
module.js:434
  return process.dlopen(module, path._makeLong(filename));   
                 ^
Error: The specified module could not be found.
\\?\C:\Users\...\node_modules\opencv\build\opencv\v6.0.0\Release\node-v46-win32-x64\opencv.node
    at Error (native)
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:434:18)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\...\node_modules\opencv\lib\bindings.js:4:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)`
```

I tried to start "cmd" as a root. After that the error is gone. But I want to deploy my project on a hosting and anyone won't give me administrative privileges... So I need a tip that let me start app as simple user.

I'm running node v4.8.3, NPM 4.5.0.

Comment: I'm running node v4.8.3, npm 4.5.0

Comment: When adding additional information, Instead of adding a comment, you should edit your question. I have added that information about your NPM and node versions to your question. Learn more about comments including when to comment and when not to in [the Comment help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Answer (score 0):

This means that the DLLs can not be opened. You either don't have the opencv binaries dir in your system path or the DLLs do not match the .lib or .so files that you linked against.